# PHP username welcome message not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to dislplay a "welcome, username !" , but it's always dislaying "not working".
How can i fix this ?

This is the index_l.php page content:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username']) {
echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!";
}
else{
  echo "not working";
}
?>
```

This is the login script:

```
<?php

include('connect.php');

// username and password sent from form 

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];


// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $username, $password and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['username'];
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
header("location:index_l.php");
}
else {
echo "Problem";
}
?>
```

Comment: Surely you are loading `session_start();` right? Ah, knew it. ;-)

Comment: Did you even start a session? Add a `session_start();` to your file at the top. Well all your files using `$_SESSION`.

Comment: All you really need is `if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){...}` unless you've assigned that variable to a particular name or row etc. As in `if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] == "you"){...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session variable does not have a value.

```
$_SESSION['username']
```

Also,

You have to add

```
session_start();
```

at the very beginning in both files index_l.php and login script

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't work because `$_SESSION['username']` doesn't have a value:

```
$_SESSION['username'];
```

You might want to set it the value of `$username`:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Comment: So to fix change to `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`.  Now whether or not you should be storing unencrypted passwords is another question....